# Is the map conformal at infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Consider the map defined as following:
$$f(z)=\begin{cases}
\frac{z-1}{z}  & \text{if $z \neq 0, \infty$ } \\
\infty & \text{if $z=0$ }\\
1 & \text{if $z=\infty$}
\end{cases}$$

To see if this map is conformal at $\infty$, we should check if $f(1/z)$ is conformal at 0. But then we have:
$$f(1/z)=\begin{cases}
1-z  & \text{if $z \neq 0, \infty$ } \\
\infty & \text{if $z=0$ }\\
1 & \text{if $z=\infty$}
\end{cases}$$
How does this tell me if $f(1/z)$ is conformal at 0? Any help are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to invert the variable at $z=0$ and at $z=\infty$.

$f(1/z)=\infty$ for $z=\infty$

and

$f(1/z)=1$ for $z=0$.

Then $g(z)=f(1/z)=1-z$ near $z=0$, which is analytic, with derivative $g'(0)=-1\neq0$, and therefore conformal.

Comment: If you split g(z) into $g(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, then won't you have $v(x,y) = -y)$ for $z \neq 0, \infty$ and $v(x,y) = 1$ for $z = 0$, so the partial derivative of v with respect to y is discontinuous at $z=0$, which implies $g(z)$ is not even real differentiable at $z=0$? What's wrong with my reasoning? Thanks

Comment: @user428487 The partial derivative $v_y$ of $v$ is constant equal to $-1$. And that includes at $(0,0)$. Compute $v_y(0,0)=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{v(0,y)-v(0,0)}{y}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{-y-0}{y}=-1$